# Microfacets Theory: A CDF for normal distribution given incident direction

Tags: cdf

The paper [Microfacet Models for Refraction through Rough Surfaces](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~srm/publications/EGSR07-btdf.pdf), page 3 section 3.1, describes the NDF. 
The problem: Given incident ray `v` I'd like to generate a CDF `F` that given an angle `θ` gives the probability that normals are distributed at or less than θ from `v`, i.e. `dot(v,m)<=cos(θ)` w.p. `F(θ)`.

For `v = n` where `n` is the macrosurface normal this is simple (Assuming isotropic NDF):

[image: formula1]

Which is very easy to compute for the common GGX or Beckmann NDFs.

The paper gives the formula [image: formula2] but it is harder to integrate and still not useful.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Should it be on math?

Comment: Is there a question here?